# Laravel возвращает неправильный url сохраненного файла

Tags: php, laravel

**Laravel 9.**

Делаю сохранение файла по мануалу.

Принимаю файл в контроллере, сохраняю а затем вывожу таким образом:

```
$path = Storage::putFile('public/images',  $request->file('file'));
// $path = '/public/images/4KcHzi8tDEIrevLgByYBYsM2w2THsG7Q5aAkkWMw.png'

return asset($path);
```

выполнил команду

```
php artisan storage:link
```

после этого картинка, фактически, доступна по адресу:

```
сайт.ру/files/images/4KcHzi8tDEIrevLgByYBYsM2w2THsG7Q5aAkkWMw.png
```

но laravel возвращает неправильный URL:

```
сайт.ру/public/images/4KcHzi8tDEIrevLgByYBYsM2w2THsG7Q5aAkkWMw.png
```

файл сохраняется по пути:

```
<корень>/storage/app/public/images/4KcHzi8tDEIrevLgByYBYsM2w2THsG7Q5aAkkWMw.png
```

Мои массив конфиг с дисками и символическими ссылками

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/files',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
        'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
        'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
    ],

],

'links' => [
    public_path('files') => storage_path('app/public'),
],
```

как это исправить, как сделать чтобы URL возвращался какой надо? может быть надо дополнительно определить что-то в конфигах?

### Дополнение

Пока лучшее, что смог получить, это
вернуть URL

```
Storage::disk('public')->url($path)
//сайт.ру/files/public/images/4KcHzi8tDEIrevLgByYBYsM2w2THsG7Q5aAkkWMw.png
```

Нужно только понять, как избивиться от этого public в адресе

Comment: Нужно сделать `php artisan storage:link`. [Доки](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#the-public-disk)

Comment: Сделал иначе бы у меня вообще файл не был доступен по урлу

Comment: Так уберите с `putFile` public, Вы же его уже в руте указали. Само собой оно Вам пытается сохранить в `/storage/app/public/public/images`

Comment: Если уберу он сохранит вне папки public то есть на одном уровне с ней. И, кроме того, при попытке получить урл выдаст ошибку якобы я пытаюсь получить URL к файлу который не лежит в  public. Это стоковый laravel. Дополнительно я здесь ничего не настраивал. Попробую еще поперебирать варианты.